# "npm run deploy" not working after trying to deploy my react app to github

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

"npm run deploy" not working after trying to deploy my react app to github and getting: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:s<path\build>'`C:\Users\USER 2021\Desktop\robotfriends>npm run deploy` npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> robotfriends@0.1.0 predeploy
> npm run build

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> robotfriends@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

> robotfriends@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\USER 2021\Desktop\robotfriends\build'

here's my Package.json :

```
{
  "homepage": "https://Aligumi.github.io/robotfriends",
  "name": "robotfriends",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "tachyons": "^4.12.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution my self! :)
I had to run `npm run build` to create the build folder. Then ran `npm run deploy`